# Preventing PHP from deleting temp memory

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload, temp

I have a form system where the user selects the files they want to upload and when they select the files, I use Javascript to do a basic scan on the files to verify they are allowed and the right size, then I have PHP do another scan to catch anything the Javascript bit may have missed. The problem is once the PHP bit finished it deletes the temp files, so when I go to upload them they no longer exist. Is there a way I can make the PHP part not delete the temp files, during the scan, so it can upload them later on when the user submits the form?

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are deleted after the script completes. There's a built-in function for moving them elsewhere; of course, it's then your responsibility to clean them up yourself, when you o longer need them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Ok. That is unfortunate, That is not what I was looking for, but the more I thought about it, the more I realized, the files have to be uploaded to the server before I can even check them with PHP which defeats what I was trying to do, which was not upload them until I wanted to upload them.

Comment: Aha, that's what wasn't making sense. Indeed, for any server-side checks, the files need to get to the server first; client-side checking with JS is limited - I understand you could make a Flash uploader, which is more powerful on the client side, but then device support goes out of the window :(

Comment: Yeah, that's not something we want to do. Well thanks for the help anyway.